# How to center content image in :after element

Tags: css

I use a :after element with an image and it works great. But I would like to centre the :after element (the image) in the center of the page meanwhile, the normal small element is left-aligned text.

The element is a display inline-block but the parent element doesn't allows it to centre it.

**CSS**

```
.bold_option_textbox span.bold_help_text:first-of-type>small:after {
    content: url(https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1595/2013/files/PRINT-YOUR-NAME.png?3077);
    width: 314px; 
    height: 176px;
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:center;
  }
```

**HTML**

```
<span class="bold_help_text">
<small>Text Content</small>
</span>
```

I expect it to center but it cant center because it's a :after element and response to its parent. The bold_help_text item is in center of the page.

live preview of the page elements: https://wildpurpose.com/pages/ambassador-package

Comment: `display:block` instead of `inline-block`, plus `margin: auto`, done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please insert these two properties in your css
margin-left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, 0);

```css
   .bold_option_textbox span.bold_help_text:first-of-type>small:after {
content: url(https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1595/2013/files/PRINT-YOUR-NAME.png?3077);
width: 314px;
height: 176px;
display: inline-block;
text-align: center;
margin-left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}
```

```html
<span class="bold_help_text">
<small>Text Content</small>
</span>
```

Comment: That made it, thanks a lot! Saved me so much time, really really appreciate it!

Comment: Happy to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Plz add this style..

**CSS**

```
.bold_option_textbox span.bold_help_text:first-of-type>small {
  text-align:center;
}
.bold_option_textbox span.bold_help_text:first-of-type>small::after {
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sry.. plz try display:block instead of display:inline-block..

**CSS**

```
.bold_option_textbox span.bold_help_text:first-of-type>small:after {
  display:block;
}
```